# Get coordinates from a lambda function point

Tags: python, scipy, lambda

I am fitting data to certain curves.
I have a model lambda function and I would like to obtain the exact coordinates (x,y) of the maximum point of it.
I am able to know the maximum value, however, I also need to know its position in x-axis.
Is that possible?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
   from pylab import *
   from scipy import optimize

   fitf = lambda f, x: f[0]*(1/(1+((x-f[1])/f[2])**2))
   errf = lambda f, x, y: fitf(f, x) - y 
   f0 = [0, 1, 2] 
   f1, success = optimize.leastsq(errf, f0[:], args=(x, y))

   pos = linspace(100, 100, 1000)
   max = fitf_voigt(f1, pos).max()

   print 'Peak max = %f' %max
```

args(x, y) come from my experimental data.

Comment: `fitf` looks way to long and complex to be a `lambda` function...consider using a standard `def` function to make it more readable.

Comment: You are right, however the function does not really matters. I find lambda functions more comfortable for trials, so I've copied it. I've just shortened the function.

Comment: @Lorena: Are you using `numpy` or `scipy`? If so, it would be helpful to tag your question as such.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCornett, I am using scipy. I will add both, the header and the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the position of the maximal value using the `argmax` function:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.random.randn(100)
In [3]: x.max()
Out[3]: 2.6054091710887723 
In [4]: x.argmax()
Out[4]: 27
In [5]: x[27]
Out[5]: 2.6054091710887723
In [6]: x[27] == x.max()
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor, I had thought about something more directly obtained from the lambda function itself, but this also solved my problem.